# Nested if(isset) is not working as intended

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a nested `if (isset)` but it doesn't seem to work as I intended. I also tried `if (!empty)`. Please see the code below.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
   if(isset($_FILES['userFile'])){
     //upload file, make tumbnail, then put info to the the tables on the database
     //header location
   } else if (isset($_POST['comment'])){
     //put info to the tables on the database
     //header location

   } else {
     die("you didn't write a comment or upload a file");
   }
}
```

My intention was to let user upload a pic without a comment or let him or her comment without uploading a picture and obviously not letting the user to send an empty form. I searched a bit but I didn't find much info about nested isset or empty.

Am I on the right track? if so; how can I make this one work?

Because when I try the code above without setting a `userFile`, it still gives me the error from the `userFile` part and the part is like below:

```
if($imagesize2 > $max_size2) {
    die("your file is bigger than max size");
} else if($safe_imagetype2 =='image/jpeg' || $safe_imagetype2 =='image/png' || $safe_imagetype2 == 'image/jpg' || $safe_imagetype2 == 'image/gif') {
    move_uploaded_file($safe_uploadTmp2, "./images/$safe_uploadName2");
} else {
    die("it must be gif, jpg or png");
}
```

any help appreciated.

Comment: I would start with debugging this. Try to var_dump the contents of your POST and see whats in there.

Comment: file uploads go into $_FILE, not $_POST.

Comment: @MarcB my bad the  original code has it as `$_FILES['userFile']`, I'll edit the question too.

Comment: and what's the error you get? checking for the existence `$_FILES['userFile']` is NOT how you check if a file was uploaeded or not. If you have an `<input type="file">` you WILL get a $_FILEs entry for it, regardlesss of what (if anything) got uploaded. you need to check `$_FILES['userFIle']['error']` to see what happened.

Comment: as I tried to explain I get the  `else {
    die("it must be gif, jpg or png");
}` part when I try to post the form without setting a file. So yea I guess `if (isset($_FILES['userFile']))` part is being ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you're looking for.

```
if(isset($_FILES['userFile']) && strlen($_FILES['userFile']['inputNAME']) > 1)
```

Comment: this let me pass the user file part without setting but now it says "you didnt enter a comment or uploaded a picture" so now I can't get the comment part checked. I tried `strlen` with comment part.

`} else if(!empty($_POST['comments']) && strlen($_POST['comments']) > 1) {` still not working


edit: I gave you 1 upvote bcs it works for the first part. I'll probably accept your answer when I find my mistake. thank you

Answer (score 2):

You should to check [the error during the file upload](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) this way:

```
if (isset($_FILES['userFile']) && UPLOAD_ERR_OK == $_FILES['userFile']['error']) {
    // The file has been uploaded successfully
}
```

Comment: Not at all. This is actually the only way to make sure that the file has been uploaded successfully.